# PHP retrieving data from a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having a bit of an issue retrieving and formatting the retrieved info in a way that I intend it to.

Basically I have products IDs that match categories IDs. A product can have multiple categories, and I get the results as expected. But I am trying to format it in a way that for every Product I get a list of Category IDs. Right now I get multiple Product IDs for every Category ID, as such:

```
Product Id: 65 ––> Categories Id:250
Product Id: 65 ––> Categories Id:249
Product Id: 66 ––> Categories Id:250
Product Id: 66 ––> Categories Id:249
Product Id: 66 ––> Categories Id:252
Product Id: 66 ––> Categories Id:251
Product Id: 66 ––> Categories Id:276
Product Id: 66 ––> Categories Id:268
Product Id: 66 ––> Categories Id:255
```

I need it to be more like:

```
Product Id: 65 ––> Categories Id:250, 249
Product Id: 66 ––> Categories Id:250, 249, 252, 251, 276,268, 255
```

Here is the code I have doing the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products_categories` ORDER BY `products_categories`.`productid` ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "Product Id: " . $row["productid"] . "  ––>  " . "Categories Id:" . $row["categoryid"] . "<br>";
   }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}
```

Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: We need more info on the MySQL tables structures, and what the relationship is : one-to-many, many-to-many? Do you use a join table (3rd MySQL table) ?

Comment: The structure of the table is very similar what I am getting right now. basically Multiple Product IDs for every Category ID they belong to. This particular table just has this relationship in it. I eventually need to retrieve the name associated with the Category, but as long as I can get the list of Category IDs in a single Product ID structure, would be good. And of course a Category has Multiple Product IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT productid, GROUP_CONCAT(categoryid) as categoryid
FROM products_categories
group by productid
order by productid
```

Comment: PyQL, Perfect. One last question, How can I add a space after every categoryid? I tried concatenating a " " after $row["categoryid"] but no results. Thank you again.

Comment: Figured it out...forgot about the SEPARATOR... Thank you again. If anyone in the future is looking for the same results, just use this: GROUP_CONCAT(categoryid SEPARATOR ', ')